# Skip Footer lines from the CSV Input file starting from the last by given skip lines count in Java

Tags: java, backend

This is the sample CSV File, it was separated by header and footer
so here I need to skip the last two lines from the input. I need only the two lines starting from 2234.... I want to skip those two lines starting from AccountNo....

`223435434,CDF,0.00,-591.93,591.93,0.00,0.00,0.00,591.93 223435434,CDF,0.00,-591.93,591.93,0.00,0.00,0.00,591.93 AccountNo,Currency,EQ_SettledCashBalance,EQ_OutstandingCash,EQ_TotalCashBalance,ETO_SettledCashBalance,ETO_OutstandingCash,ETO_TotalCashBalance,TotalCashBalance AccountNo,Currency,EQ_SettledCashBalance,EQ_OutstandingCash,EQ_TotalCashBalance,ETO_SettledCashBalance,ETO_OutstandingCash,ETO_TotalCashBalance,TotalCashBalance`

Here is the Header code,

```
                .when(PredicateBuilder.and(header(Constants.EXCLUDE_HEADER).isEqualTo(Constants.HEADER),
                        header(Exchange.SPLIT_INDEX).isLessThan(serviceMetaData.getSkipLines()))) // Skip configurable number of records
                        .to(Constants.DUMMY_URI)
                        .endChoice()
```

The footer code as below,

```
 //remove footer
                .when(PredicateBuilder.and(header(Constants.EXCLUDE_FOOTER).isEqualTo(Constants.FOOTER),
                        header(Exchange.SPLIT_COMPLETE).isLessThan(serviceMetaData.getSkipLines())))
                .to(Constants.DUMMY_URI)
                .endChoice()
```

I need to modify the footer code
to skip the lines from the last as per given Skip line count using java.

Thanks for your support

I need to modify the footer code
to skip the lines from the last as per given Skip line count using java.